# react async select add new options in select not getting updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

how to add option to [react-select/async](https://react-select.com/async) component explicitly on click of add option , I'm not able to update options , but state is getting updated !!
is there any other way to achive this ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const optionsData = [
    { value: "Spring", label: "Spring" },
    { value: "Summer", label: "Summer" },
    { value: "Autumn", label: "Autumn" },
    { value: "Winter", label: "Winter" }
  ];

  const [options, setOptions] = useState(optionsData);

  const loadOptions = (inputValue) => {
    console.log(inputValue, "pppp");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // using setTimeout to emulate a call to server
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(filter(inputValue));
      }, 2000);
    });
  };

  const filter = (inputValue) =>
    options.filter((option) =>
      option.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
    );
  const handleAddOption = () => {
    const newOptions = [
      { value: "Apple", label: "Apple" },
      { value: "Ball", label: "Ball" }
    ];
    setOptions((prevState) => [...prevState, ...newOptions]);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
      <div style={{ width: "400px" }}>
        <AsyncSelect defaultOptions cacheOptions loadOptions={loadOptions} />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleAddOption}>ADD OPTIONS</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

***[CODESANDBOX LINK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-async-forked-6md9b?file=/src/index.js:0-1406)***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `options` state as the value of `defaultOptions` prop of `AsyncSelect` component. From the docs about [defaultOptions](https://react-select.com/async#defaultoptions):

> Providing an option array to this prop will populate the initial set of options used when opening the select, at which point the remote load only occurs when filtering the options (typing in the control)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const optionsData = [
    { value: "Spring", label: "Spring" },
    { value: "Summer", label: "Summer" },
    { value: "Autumn", label: "Autumn" },
    { value: "Winter", label: "Winter" }
  ];
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(optionsData);

  const loadOptions = (inputValue) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // using setTimeout to emulate a call to server
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(filter(inputValue));
      }, 2000);
    });
  };

  const filter = (inputValue) =>
    options.filter((option) =>
      option.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
    );

  const handleAddOption = () => {
    const newOptions = [
      { value: "Apple", label: "Apple" },
      { value: "Ball", label: "Ball" }
    ];
    setOptions((prevState) => [...prevState, ...newOptions]);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
      <div style={{ width: "400px" }}>
        <AsyncSelect
          defaultOptions={options}
          cacheOptions
          loadOptions={loadOptions}
        />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleAddOption}>ADD OPTIONS</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-async-forked-lotxv?file=/src/index.js:0-1420)